# On load, redirect page in new tab/window

Tags: html, redirect

I have access to a page template but no access to the header template (don't ask me how!), I need to create an instant page redirect on that template. It's needs to open in a new window.

It doesn't really matter how it's done just that it opens in a new window and please bear in mind I don't have access to the header template.

Comment: Are you wanting to do this via html and javascript?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I could be a bit off here (please correct me if i am) but,
you just the page to open a new page then something like this

[See this for detailed usage of window.open.](http://www.javascript-coder.com/window-popup/javascript-window-open.phtml)

You can pass html into the function as well.

`<body onload="window.open(yourwindow)">`

Or if you were just wanting a redirect to an existing page then 


[See this for detailed usage of window.location.](http://www.tizag.com/javascriptT/javascriptredirect.php)

`<body onload=window.location='www.yourlocation.com'>`

Pass that whatever you want for parameters into the url.

Or if you were looking to grab some info from the page before you transition then you could just write a function that grabs the data you need from the header and pass that to the new page.